# PPT show in lightbox (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, powerpoint, lightbox

A client is asking for PPT slide show to appear in lightbox when some one click the image. I have tried searching every where, but to no avail. I have not found any plugin nor a good way to get the things done. I am not very experienced with Wordpress. Can anyone suggests a good method to get things done? Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Probably start here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx and wrap it in some kind of lightbox code.

Comment: That site doesn't work for me in Safari, Chrome, or Firefox.  Maybe it's because I'm on a Mac, but I do have Office installed.  In any case, that doesn't seem like it's a solution that can be relied on. I would try to push back on this request - I doubt there's any easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work here in MSIE or Chrome either.  I think maybe something's horked at the MS server end.  Imagine that.

You might want to follow the instrux to see if it works with a file hosted on your own site.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.. you showed interest in this.. But I actually found a solution. I actually found 2 plugins to do the work. For gallery and lightbox I found

http://codecanyon.net/item/media-grid-wordpress-responsive-portfolio/2218545

And for PPT/PDF embedding I am using

http://codecanyon.net/item/embed-any-document-plus-wordpress-plugin/9911763?ref=awsmin

These have made my life very simple.. :)

I hope if some reaches to this question, solution is ready..!!!